# PHP MySQL SELECT Statement with bindparam doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my code:

```
function getUsers($connection ,$username) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("s", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    return  $stmt->fetchAll();  
}

$voornaam = "dave";
$users = getUsers($connection, $voornaam);
print_r($users);
```

When I open my webpage, I get an empty Array.
I checked, and there is a user with the username "dave" in my database.
This should work, however, it doesn't...
Anyone knows what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is PDO. bindParam should be `1` if you use question marks as placeholders

Comment: But its interesting that OP's code still returns an empty array. I expected an error to be thrown when `execute()` isn't called

Answer (score 0):

First is, you have to execute it before using fetchAll():

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This is the correct way:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
```

If you want to user ? it will determine the order of ? in bindParam, use it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = ?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

More example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

Comment: your answer still won't work. something needs to happen after binding

Comment: @Rotimi updated the answer, you missing execute() function

Comment: I'm not the OP though ;)

Comment: Oh haha @Rotimi

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$stmt->bindParam("s", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

you need to use

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Check this link for details https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam

You need to check this *Example #2 Execute a prepared statement with question mark placeholders*
This is the correct way

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
return  $stmt->fetchAll();
```